# It is possible to maintain two tableviews and one viewcontroller in segmented controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a doubt how to maintain two tableviews and one view controller in segmented controller. In `segment=0` I want display first tableview, In `segment=1` to display second tableview and `segment=2` to display one view controller, is it possible?

Comment: ya it is possible , use tags for each thing ,show

Comment: Instead of having two tables, have two data sources for both segments, will save lot of work and time

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is possible. There are two ways.

1. Use single tableview. And based on segment, change the tableview values.
2. Use two custom tableview class, and custom Protocal/delegate methods to manage the events.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to have 2 `Tableview`s. Based on the segment selection call `[tableview reloaddata]` with  your data what to display on that segment section. This saves lot of efforts and manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I think a scrollView can help you solve you problem:

Just add the two tableViews on the scrollView and use the segmentedController's method to set the scrollView's contentOffset.x

Similarly, you can add the ViewController on the scrollView followed the two tableView and scroll to it by click the segment == 2

Hope that my advice can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're using one or multiple table views, the main idea is to handle the selection event.

If your segmented control is created in the storyboard, you can use the @IBAction outlet, alternately you can use the 'addTarget' syntax.

e.g:

```
 mySegmentedControl.addTarget(self, #selector(myHandlerMethod(_:), for: .valueChanged)
```

where the handler method is something like:

(first case)

```
@IBAction func myHandlerMethod(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

}
```

(second case)

```
@objc func myHandlerMethod(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        // handle your table view reloading or switching between first and second table views. 
    } else {
        // otherwise, do something else
    }
}
```

Some additional thoughts:

- I would agree with others in using a single table view and giving it a different set of data. You can use different subclasses of UITableViewCell to represent your data if the content format between your data sets is different in structure and meaning.
- It might also be worth looking into using child view controllers instead of plain views/table views. That way you can encapsulate logic relating to each specific scene you want to present inside a view controller and manage it independently.